# Changing value of property

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uikit

i have two view controllers, aViewController and bViewController, bViewController is a subclass of aViewController. I have some properties declared in aViewController, in bViewController i can read the value of that properties but if i try to change their values, the value doesn't change and remain the first before the changing.

Comment: Post the relevant code or no one can help.

Comment: Code or it didn't happen.

Comment: Maybe the property is in "copy" mode

Comment: What i suspect is he created a new instance and expecting to change the previous instance's value.

Comment: Yes, i've checked the memory address of the properties and they change when i read value and then when i write. I've tried to change the property with retain or copy but same result

Comment: This is again the same question, How to access other class variable from this class. Search you will find many answers.....

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you have something like this:

```
// "A" view controller
@interface AViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;

@end


// "B" view controller
@interface BViewController : AViewController

- (void)changePropertyValue;

@end

@implementation BViewController

- (void)changePropertyValue
{
    self.name = @"Bill";
    NSLog(self.name);
    self.name = @"Steve";
    NSLog(self.name);
}

@end

// create your BViewController
BViewController *theController = [[BViewController alloc] init];
[theController changePropertyValue];
```

Comment: Ok, this is correct but my problem is that i want to read the new value, changed in bViewController, in the aViewController